# How to know which libraries are being used in an android app

Tags: java, android

I've just seen that AppBrain site gets statistics about which are the most popular dev libraries in the android market.

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/dev

So I guess that having the app apk is it possible to know which libraries are being used in that app. Do you have any idea  how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

When building the apk, all the resources from all the libraries are moved to one "res" folder, which is found in the apk, 
the apk is just a zip file with different extention.

I believe appbrain has a list of some resources from each library, for example:

ActionBarSherlock: /res/drawable-v11/abs__progress_medium_holo.xml

ViewPagerIndicatior: /res/color/vpi__dark_theme.xml

HoloEveryWhere: /res/drawable/btn_group_holo_dark.xml

etc...

And to find the libraries, it gets the list of the resources folder which is not encrypted and  compares the files paths with the previously saved patterns.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reverse engineering tools that you can use to see the contents of an apk. Here are some examples

https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar

Also it's good to keep in mind when you develop your apps that unless you obfuscate (you can use Proguard for this) your code it's easy to get a hold of your source code from the apk.

Comment: I am sure appbrain doesnt reverse engineer to find out what libraries are used.. Should be some other way..

Comment: I have no idea how appbrain do it, but these are tools that allow you to see what's inside the apk and thus also what libraries were used